# Can my in-laws travel to UK without a visa, with an Italian article 10 residence card?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, family, freedom-of-movement

I am an EEA national and my wife and her parents are European Union residence card holders. Can my in laws travel to the UK without a visa?

Comment: @Glorfindel "European" should be preceded by "a," not "an."

Answer (score 3):

Only if you're already in the UK **or** you're travelling with them. In that case they can enter by presenting their passport and residence card.

Comment: And only if the UK doesn't crash out of the EU in 6 months :)

Comment: But airline boarding did not allow them to go but immigration told them they can go

Comment: @Singhjagroop The check-in staff was wrong then. Tell them to check the TIMATIC database, which says "Visa required, except for Passengers with a "Permanent
Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union Citizen" or a
 Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union Citizen  issued by Italy to to family members of a national of
  Switzerland or an EEA Member State. They must
  travel with or travel to join the national of Switzerland or

  EEA Member State."

Comment: @Singhjagroop Also contact the Airline and get compensation, again quoting TIMATIC